# How to activate multiple GPUs on one motherboard?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, lubuntu

I have connected 2 GPUs nvidia GTX 1070 on lubuntu 16.04.03 through PCIe raisers. So far I was only able to see one of them, the other one is simply unavalable, even if I disconnect one and reconnect the other one. Each of them works, just not together.

```
lspci -v | grep NVIDIA
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1b81 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
03:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f0 (rev a1)
```

Is there something else I need to configure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure multi gpu on lubunut 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000449/how-to-configure-multi-gpu-on-lubunut-16-04)

Comment: Your output displays only one card - so the other is not recognized?

Answer (score 0):

Lucky you!  My $435 GTX-1070 order was canceled by NewEgg as "out of stock" but I see the same one going for $1200 the last time I looked.  Checking around, the only way I can get one at a reasonable price is to buy a system.

I have pair of gtx-1050 TI on each of two uBuntu 4.13.0-19-generic.  This was 17.04 as I recall.  `lspci -v` clearly shows them. While not in x1 risers, they are in x8 adapters.  After installing 17.04 I then installed nVidia CUDA tool version 384 (not just the 384 driver).

I assume you did the same?
What motherboard are you using?

Comment: I just installed the 384 driver. Is the CUDA tool solving this issue?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, just about all mining using graphics boards uses opencl.  https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/gpu.html  You will need the CUDA "run" package.  Google "ubuntu cuda" and go to nVidia where they got info on various linux system.  Be aware that CUDA has a problem with the latest kernel, 32.  Eventually it will be fixed.  I had to use the 19 generic kernel as the 32 failed to install cuda.